# Prove that definitions of the limit superior are equivalent

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing

> Let $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a real sequence. And let $L^+$ be an extended real number (i.e. $L^+\in\mathbb{R}^*$). Then TFAE:
>
> (1) $L^+$ = $\displaystyle\inf_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\sup_{k{\geq}n}(a_k)$ = $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup_{k{\geq}n}(a_k)$
>
> (2) $L^+$ = $\sup\{p\in\mathbb{R}^*:p$ is a cluster point of $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\}$
>
> (3) $L^+$ is a (or the unique) number in $\mathbb{R}^*$ satisfying: (i) For all $\epsilon\gt 0$ there exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $a_n\lt L^++\epsilon$ for all $n\ge N$ (ii) For all $\epsilon\gt 0$ and $N\in\mathbb{N}$ there exists $n\ge N$ such that $a_n\gt L^+-\epsilon$ (or alternatively (i) For all $x\gt L^+$ there exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $a_n\lt x$ for all $n\ge N$ (ii) For all $x\lt L^+$ and $N\in\mathbb{N}$ there exists $n\ge N$ such that $a_n\gt x$)
>
> The extended real number $L^+$ satisfying any of the above statement is called **the limit superior** of $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$

**Question: To show these definitions are equivalent, I have no problem proving (1) $\Rightarrow$ (3) and (3) $\Rightarrow$ (2), but how to prove (2) $\Rightarrow$ (1)?**

**(If this is duplicate, please link to an answer really address this question.)**

P.S. (1) is the definition according to Wikipedia and Terrence Tao's *Analysis I*, (2) is according to Rudin's *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* and Marsden's *Elementary Classical Analysis*, and (3) is according to Apostol's *Mathematical Analysis*

Answer (score 0):

Proof of (2) $\Rightarrow$ (1):

Denote $l$ = $\displaystyle\inf_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\sup_{k{\geq}n}(a_k)$ = $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup_{k{\geq}n}(a_k)$

Suppose by way of contradiction that $L^+\gt l$

Then there exists $p\in\mathbb{R}^*$ such that (i) $p$ is a cluster point of $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ and (ii) $p\gt l$

By (ii) we also have $\displaystyle p\gt\frac{1}{2}(p+l)\gt l$ = $\displaystyle\inf_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\sup_{k{\geq}n}(a_k)$

Hence $\displaystyle\sup_{k\ge K}a_k\lt\frac{1}{2}(p+l)$ for some $K\in\mathbb{N}$

Hence $\displaystyle a_k\lt\frac{1}{2}(p+l)$ for all $k\ge K$

Hence $\displaystyle\#\{k\in\mathbb{N}:|a_k-p|\lt\frac{1}{2}(p-l)\}\lt\infty$

Hence $p$ is not a cluster point of $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$. A contradicttion to (i)

Hence $L^+\le l$

Now given $\epsilon\gt 0$

There exists $N_{\epsilon}$ such that $\displaystyle l\le\sup_{k\ge N_{\epsilon}}a_k\lt l+\epsilon$

Since $\displaystyle(\sup_{k\ge j}a_k)_{j\in\mathbb{N}}$ is decreasing

We have $j\ge N_{\epsilon}$ implies (i) $\displaystyle l\le\sup_{k\ge j}a_k$ and (ii) $\displaystyle\sup_{k\ge j}a_k\lt l+\epsilon$

By (ii) we have $a_k\lt l+\epsilon$ for all $k\ge j$

By (i) we have $l\le a_{k_{j}}$ for some $k_j\ge j$

Hence $l\le a_{k_{j}}\lt l+\epsilon$ for some $k_j\ge j$ for all $j\ge N_{\epsilon}$

Hence $\#\{k\in\mathbb{N}:a_k\in(l-\epsilon, l+\epsilon)\}$ = $\infty$

Hence $l$ is a cluster point of $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$

Hence $L^+\ge l$

By the above argument we conclude that $L^+$ = $l$

Comment: Of course this is a newbie formal proof. I may lost some cases to consider. Some lines may appeared illogically. If there are some healthy comments or editings I will appreciate.